# Candy Machine V2 Limit WL Token Usage to a certain number

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine, solana-cli

With Candy Machine V2 is there any way to limit the number of usages for each whitelist token to a certain number? For example, I would like to send each whitelist user one token that can be used to mint 3 times, and then it is burned so it can't be used more than that. This would be ideal.

Or would I need to send each whitelist user 3 different tokens and then burn each one after it is used once?

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the whitelist docs ([deprecated js-CLI](https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/archived/candy-machine-v2/configuration#whitelist-settings) and [sugar](https://docs.metaplex.com/tools/sugar/configuration)).

You have 2 options about how the whitelist token will be used: burnEveryTime or neverBurn.

If you set burnEveryTime then each time the user mint 1 WL-token will be burned (make sure ur WL-token has 0 decimals in order to burn exactly 1 unit).

If you set neverBurn then the user will be able to mint with 1 WL-token any number of NFTs.

So in order to allow the user to mint X times with its WL-token you have to send him the exact amount of WL-token that you wanna allow each user to mint and set burnEveryTime, so the person will be able to Mint X NFTs and he will burn 1 WL-token per mint, so X burned WL-tokens.

Comment: ok yea I read the docs and have used both of those options before but wanted to confirm if there was a middle ground between burnEveryTime and neverBurn